# Add label with for loop in different coordinates

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, uilabel

I wan't to add labels (strings from an array) onto buttons with a for loop.

I'm new in objective-c and I don't know how I can fit all the changes into the loop on each iteration.
If there is a better way to do this, please show me. Right now I got this, which only prints the second element in the array out at upper right corner.

```
for (int i=0; i< sizeof(arrayOfLetters);  i++ ) {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(441,11,30,20)];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayOfLetters objectAtIndex:1]];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. You want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfLetters.count; i++) {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(441, 11 + i * 25, 30, 20)];
    label.text = arrayOfLetters[i];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
}
```

You should also give each label a different frame as I did here. Adjust as needed.

Keep in mind that the `sizeof` function gives you the size of the variable. Since `arrayOfLetters` is an object pointer the result will probably be 4. You want the actual count of the array. See the docs for `NSArray`.

Also, do not needlessly use `stringWithFormat:`. Only use it when you actually have a string that needs formatting.